# Ruby ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I have been facing this error when I try to call my api using `GET /lecture_events/1`.
The error is

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)):
  
app/controllers/lecture_events_controller.rb:46:in `set_lecture_event'
```

and this is my lecture_events controller code

```
class LectureEventsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_lecture_event, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /lecture_events
  def index
    @lecture_events = LectureEvent.all

    render json: @lecture_events
  end

  # GET /lecture_events/1
  def show
    @lecture_event = LectureEvent.find(params[:id])
    render json: @lecture_event
  end

  # POST /lecture_events
  def create
    @lecture_event = LectureEvent.new(lecture_event_params)

    if @lecture_event.save
      render json: @lecture_event, status: :created, location: @lecture_event
    else
      render json: @lecture_event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /lecture_events/1
  def update
    if @lecture_event.update(lecture_event_params)
      render json: @lecture_event
    else
      render json: @lecture_event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  # DELETE /lecture_events/1
  def destroy
    @lecture_event = LectureEvent.find(params[:userID])
    @lecture_event.destroy
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_lecture_event
      @lecture_event = LectureEvent.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def lecture_event_params
      params.require(:lecture_event).permit(:timestamp, :eventType, :lectureID, :userID)
    end
end
```

I have been trying to debug the function in question but after going through the docs I'm pretty sure thats how `modelName.find()` is called. I tried passing in a string instead of `params` but it still throws the same error.

Does anybody know what could be the problem with it ?

My rails version is `6.1.4`
Ruby is `3.0.2` and mongoid is `7.0.5`

EDIT: Here is my `LectureEvent` model code

```
class LectureEvent
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :timestamp, type: Date
  field :event_type, type: String
  field :lecture_id, type: String
  field :user_id, type: String
end
```

and the full stack trace if it's needed
[StackTrace](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AZH8k92bCFK48lvCaXFvnja9gVTEGPTV/view?usp=sharing)

EDIT2: Changed `"asd"` to the correct parameter value

Comment: This looks fine based on the ActiveRecord::Base.find method (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class). My best guess is you've overridden the find method in your LectureEvent model. Can you share your LectureEvent model?

Comment: I have added the stack trace and code in the post.

Comment: what is "asd" in `@lecture_event = LectureEvent.find("asd")`, can you change to this `@lecture_event = LectureEvent.find(field: "asd")`?

Comment: @dedypuji That's just a dummy string I was trying to pass in to see if `params` was the problem. I have updated the code to pass in the correct value.

Comment: I've no experience with mongoid and the stacktrace is unusually not helping much so the first thing I would check is if the find works in a rails console `rails c` and just try a find 'LectureEvent.find(1)`, you should either get a record back or a record not found error. Anything else may point you to a solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update:

Your version of mongoid/i18n doesn't support ruby 3.

[i18n](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/cb4a4be9a13ae03b7b6d0678a3ad00dd790ee240/lib/i18n.rb#L183) says you need to call `I18n::translate` with keyword arguments for ruby 3, but [mongoid](https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/2ca29500979513e559b25d88588d3ec356ce521a/lib/mongoid/errors/mongoid_error.rb#L48) is calling `I18n::translate` with a hash. It looks like this is fixed in the latest mongoid version, so I suggest upgrading to 7.3.4.

Note: you didn't see this error when a `LectureEvent` was found because no error needs to be translated in that case.

Comment: It kept logging stuff. Here's the stack trace from the get request if you want it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pnAXk0ptc0xeKWJvXYe2WZfEzwxpQhNL/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. I just checked my collection and there weren't any documents in it. So I created a dummy document and called the api using that document's id and it worked but the moment I sent in a dummy id it still threw me this error.

My only question now is shouldn't ruby just inform me that the document in question wasn't found and not this argument error?